# How to open 3000 port on Amazon EC2 for Docker Container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, mapping, port

I have a 3 docker containers on my EC2 server. In Security Group, I already add a TCP rule for 3000 port. 
[Security Grops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojbiG.jpg)

My Container with API must work on 3000 port.

```
sudo docker run -d -p 3000:3000 server
```

When I run

```
sudo docker ps
PORTS
0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp
```

But nmap says me:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
3000/tcp closed ppp
```

And when i try to send POST or GET request, it return me No response.

Comment: Does a `curl http://localhost:3000` work on the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

when you run the container, make sure to port it from 80 or 443 to your 3000.

`docker run -d -p 443:3000 <container>`